# Windows net.exe use driver message has invalid characters on Java

Tags: java, windows, joptionpane

I am running a Process from a Java Application to unmap a Windows Driver on Windows 10.

The message comes after run command:

`String command = String.format("C:\\Windows\\system32\\net.exe USE %s /delete /yes", BasePage.MAPPED_DRIVER);`

that is parsed with following method:

```
public String runCommand(String command) {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    String result = null;
    if (p.waitFor() != 0) {
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        if ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        result = buffer.toString();
        b.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

After run the command the message is coming with invalid Characters when printed on console or showed on a JOptionPane by using following code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, formatMessage(message),
 "Application Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

The Strings are being wrapped according to following method:

```
private String formatMessage(String msg) {
    return String.format("<html><body width=400>%s</body>" +
 "</html>", msg);
}
```

The result after show the message is:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: what is returned by `e.getMessage`? it works fine for `formatMessage("Não foi fornecida uma resposta válida")` (despite the coded message does not match picture - missing the "Please verify log file" part) (Obs: also I do not believe that `meta` is interpreted by `JOptionPane`) (Obs2: my workspace is UTF-8)

Comment: `<meta charset='ISO-8859-1'>` has no meaning here.  You should remove it.  (A charset only applies to decoding bytes;  a Java String is already a sequence of characters and there are no bytes to decode.)  My guess is that `msg` is already incorrect before you call formatMessage.  Edit your question and show the code used to read the output of the process.

Comment: Sorry guys @user85421 the original code has no meta tag. It works normally.

Comment: @VGR, I edited the answer with the code used to read the output. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is reading the output from a DOS command which most probably is using the `CP850` (Latin1) or `CP860` (Portuguese) charset (use the `CHCP` command in a DOS windows to display the actual code page).

To convert the read bytes to characters,  the charset name must be provided in the constructor of `InputStreamReader` like in:

```java
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream(), "Cp850")
);
```

<sup>I don't have a Portuguese OS so I could not test it</sup>